# Network related error while deploying a window application & used database to another pc

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

My window application works fine on my computer but when I install it on another computer a network-related error occurred...

I'm using sql server 2005, I have store the backup of the database, when i run it, it flags an error.
I'm using visual studio 10, C#,sql sever 2005
Error is..

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)""

Comment: Are you using a *different* SQL server on the other computer? if so, it's probably a configuration issue - I would advise you to first try and connect to the new SQL server using the DBMS

Comment: Have you tried connecting to `Naresh-lap` using the DBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happens it means that the program cannot connect to SQL Server with information you provided.
If for example you are trying to connect `my-server\sqlexpress`, usually you have one of this issues:

1. There is no computer named `my-server` in your network!
2. SQL Server is not installed on `my-server`.
3. Your client computer cannot reach `my-server` from the network. You can check this using `ping` command.
4. The installed SQL Server instance name on `my-server` is not `sqlexpress` (case-insensitive).
5. You have not enabled `TCP/IP` protocol for your installation instance of SQL Server in "Sql Server Configuration Manager".
6. You have not restarted SQL Server service after enabling `TCP/IP`.
7. Your SQL Server instance is not default instance, and SQL Server Browser service is not running on the server.
8. Server's firewall is preventing the client to access the server. Try turning off the firewall on the server (only to test this case).

Consider this a checklist, and start from the beginning. Check them one by one. And I hope that you find the problem.

Comment: Sir actually both computer are not in network i just want to deploy my application ,all working fine but when app start database operation it shows undermentioned error.

Comment: What do you mean of 'both computers are not in network'? Is your application on one computer and your database on another computer? If so then the computers must be connected to each other. Are they?

Comment: Are deploying your application on computer without network connection? Then you must check your SQL Server installation on the computer, and also check that you provided correct instance name on the connection string. Paste your connection string here, so we can examine your problem.

Comment: working i just modify my connecting string as u mentioned in point 4...
and got solution thank you sir...